# How would I secure /netdata, or Netdata for Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, networking, netdata

I'm following [the following guide for installing Netdata on Laravel Forge](https://medium.com/@nathobson/monitoring-server-resources-on-laravel-forge-with-netdata-140aa7d9bf28). Basically, it's opening the port 1999 used for Netdata and redirecting it to `/netdata` directory.

```
location = /netdata {
  return 301 /netdata/;
}

location ~ /netdata/(?<ndpath>.*) {
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;

  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
  proxy_set_header Connection "keep-alive";
  proxy_store off;
  proxy_pass http://netdata/$ndpath$is_args$args;

  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types *;
}
```

```
upstream netdata {
  server 127.0.0.1:19999;
  keepalive 64;
}
```

I already have an `auth` middleware defined, and how would I only allow people that pass the `auth` middleware to visit the `/netdata` route? The guide suggests only limiting it to one IP address, but that's not possible as I move around quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I have no experience with Laravel or Forge, according to this piece of [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authentication-quickstart), you have to define that functionality in your middleware. In essence, you instruct the middleware to perform a redirection only in case of successful authentication.

Perhaps you could instruct Laravel to redirect all connections (if auth is successful) to the NGINX endpoint (/netdata) which you will configure to only allow from `localhost`. Thus, a user will not be able to access `/netdata`, unless he/she is authenticated via the Laravel Middleware and then redirected from that middleware to the Nginx server.